# Dapper - How to map complex object

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, dapper

My object is:

```cs
public class ApplePrice
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, double> HourlyPrice { get; set; }
}
```

My database consists of many prices for each date and I need to return a list of `ApplePrice` objects. My queries are

```
SELECT * FROM Prices WHERE Date > getdate()-7
SELECT * FROM Prices WHERE Date = {Date}
```

How can I map objects from these queries with Dapper?

Comment: What columns do you have in Prices table? What records you expect to see in HourlyPrice property?

Comment: My colums are "Date (DateTime)", "Price(decimal)", "Hour(int)"

Comment: Which DBMS you used? MSSQL, MYSQL, Postgres?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Dapper documentation](https://www.learndapper.com/dapper-query/selecting-multiple-rows), `Query` or `QueryAsync` returns an enumerable of dynamic types (asynchronously for `QueryAsync`).

You can perform the mapping on the memory side. With *System.Linq* to group by `Date` and convert the grouped dataset as `Dictionary<int, double>` via `.ToDictionary()`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM Prices WHERE Date > getdate()-7";
    var result = (await connection.QueryAsync(sql))
        .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
        .Select(x => new ApplePrice
        {
            Date = x.Key,
            HourlyPrice = x.ToDictionary(k => k.Hour, v => v.Price)
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Depending on your DBMS and version, there is DBMS that allows you to construct the result containing the JSON object. For example:

> Via PostgreSQL (from version 11)

```
SELECT Date,
    json_agg(json_build_object(
        Hour::numeric, Price::money
    ))  AS HourlyPrice
FROM Prices 
WHERE Date > getdate()-7
GROUP BY Date
```

> Via MySQL (from version 5.7)

```
SELECT Date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT(
        Hour, Price
    )) AS HourlyPrice
FROM Prices 
WHERE Date > getdate()-7
GROUP BY Date
```

> Via SQL Server 2016 (13.x)

```
SELECT Date,
       JSON_QUERY(CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(CONCAT('{"', Hour, '":', Price, '}'), ','), ']')) AS HourlyPrice
FROM Prices 
WHERE Date > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY Date
```

With the above query (based on your DBMS & version), you can map to `List<ApplePrice>`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var sql = "<Replace with Query>";

    var result = (await connection.QueryAsync(sql))
        .Select(x => new ApplePrice
        {
            Date = x.Date
            HourlyPrice = x.HourlyPrice.ToDictionary(k => Convert.ToInt32(k.Key), v => Convert.ToDouble(v.Value))
        })
        .ToList();
}
```